# What is the link, if any, between Zero Knowledge Proof (ZKP) and Homomorphic encryption?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs

What is the link/relation, if any, between Zero Knowledge Proof (ZKP) and Homomorphic encryption?

Comment: ZKP can be used to mitigate or detect attacks against homomorphic-based multi-party protocols.

Comment: RH has a ZKP that's not public. It involves a number with is coprime to 2 while also being coprime to all odd numbers. That sounds like it's not a number, but in this system it is.

Comment: @RyanMatthew What is RH? How/why does it work, can you include citations, etc. And maybe answer then?

Comment: And what does it mean that a zero knowledge proof is not public?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are many.

- Homomorphic encryption implies ZK proofs for NP. This is simply because homomorphic encryption implies one-way functions, which imply ZKP for NP.
- Homomorphic encryption allows to compile any public-coin zero-knowledge proof into a designated-verifier non-interactive zero-knowledge proof; this was shown in the paper [Non-interactive Zero-Knowledge from
  Homomorphic Encryption](https://www.cs.stevens.edu/~nicolosi/papers/tcc06.pdf).
- Zero-knowledge proofs are not known to imply anything regarding the existence of homomorphic encryption. In fact, only very strong forms of zero-knowledge proofs were very recently [shown to imply public-key encryption](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/23c0/53da2aed967f40d3c9fa5efaf184fe7da3c2.pdf).
- Fully homomorphic encryption can be used to minimize the size of a non-interactive zero-knowledge proof, and reduce it to witness size + polynomial in the security parameter, see [this paper](https://www.cc.gatech.edu/fac/cpeikert/pubs/FHENIZK.pdf).

This is just a sample of the many interplays between the two notions; if you had more specific relations in mind, please clarify.

Comment: Thanks! what does NP stands for?

Comment: NP stands for [the class of problems solvable in nondeterministic polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)), but if you are not familiar with it, let's just say that you can interpret "zero-knowledge proof for NP" as "zero-knowledge proofs for any natural problem you could think of".